# 3-terminals magnetic tunnel junction

Tags: transistors, memory, magnetics, junction, mram

I was wondering if a 3 terminals magnetic tunnel junction can be implemented, as in the Figure.
On the bottom I have a normal metal (NM), on the top a magnetic junction (FM = ferromagnet) and I can simultaneously apply a voltage between 1-2 and 2-3. I know there are many experiments on this geometry but they inject a current between 1 and 3 and AFTER that they measure the tunnel resistance. This is how MRAM works.

Basically I would like to have a kind of transistor but with metallic components.

Do you know other references that explain what I would like to do?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It looks like a cowboy hat with some scribbles to me. Maybe neaten up your diagram and try physics SE.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make a structure where the top FM layer is pinned, and the orientation of the magnetization in the bottom layer can be changed by the direction of current flow between your nodes 1 and 3. This is basically how MRAM bits are programmed.

But the current from node 2 to node 1 or 3 will be much, much less than the current needed to change the magnetization...this current must tunnel through the insulator.

So, in some sense of the word "transistor" you could make something kind of like a transistor. But it will have a current gain much less than 1, and it may be very slow compared to normal transistors of the same size.

Comment: Thanks Elliot. I do not need to reorient the magnetisation by current injection. I would like to see how the TMR change when, simultaneously, I inject a current through the normal metal. The difference with MRAM is that I want to apply a voltage V13 and V23 and measure the tunnel current. Is this possible according to you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "inject a current through the normal metal". I also don't see why a voltage from 1 to 3 would make any difference if you are not planning to use the **current** from 1 to 3 as a means to change the magnetization of the free layer.

Comment: In the end, I will remove the bottom ferromagnetic electrode and I will make TMR measurement. To do that, I would like to simultaneously apply the in-plane voltage (V_13) and a voltage across the junction (V_23).

Comment: Now I am really confused. You no longer have magnetic tunneling if you remove the bottom FM layer. And how would you "remove" the electrode physically? These things are at nanometer scale,

Comment: I will end up with an hybrid junction Pt/MgO/FM. I mean I will grow this kind of structure from 0.